# Deserialize objects of a foreign class

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have a file containing a **string of serialized data**.

This serialized data contains a **bunch of objects from foreign classes** from which i know what attributes/methods i can expect, also their classname as well.

What i dont have is the exact class definition itself which deserialisation seems to require.

Is there any chance i can **deserialize these foreign objects** anyway and call theyre methods via reflections or anything?

Comment: No. You must have the .class file.

Comment: Serialization is data from the class, however I don't think you can find in serialization data the method implementations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919205/java-serializing-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any chance i can deserialize these foreign objects anyway and call theyre methods via reflections or anything?

I'm not aware of any API / library to do this.

While it is possible (in theory) decode the *information content* of a serialized stream in most cases, (because the [stream format / protocol](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html) includes descriptors for the classes and their fields), classes that implement `Externalizable` make it impossible in the general case.

And once you've decoded the information content, you've got to turn it into a form that is palatable to a Java programmer.